# Apache Storm 1.1.0, streamsparse 3.11.0 serialization error. int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, apache-storm

With Apache Storm 1.1.0 and [streamparse](https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse) there is an issue. After configuring serializer as "msgpack" I see the following error.  Do you know any fixes?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read. 

Serializer Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/home/ab/topology/bin/streamparse_run", line 11, in <module> sys.exit(main()) 
File "/home/ab/topology/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamparse/run.py", line 45, in main cls(serializer=args.serializer).run() 
File "/home/ab/topology/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystorm/component.py", line 483, in run storm_conf, context = self.read_handshake() 
File "/home/ab/topology/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystorm/component.py", line 311, in read_handshake pid_dir, _conf, _context = msg['pidDir'], msg['conf'], msg['context'] 

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable 

at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:96) 
at org.apache.storm.spout.ShellSpout.open(ShellSpout.java:111) 
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4976$fn__4991.invoke(executor.clj:600) 
at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:482) 
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Related projects are:

- https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse
- https://github.com/apache/storm
- https://github.com/pystorm/pystorm

Comment: Update: Contribution of Storm side msgpack serialization is still in progress https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/1136